# Javascript not working on Asp. NET

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

Can someone help me?

My js is not working, I hide the divId and when I click te button the divId should appear but nothing happens! I am sending the code below.
What am I doing wrong, could it be in the master page file?

```
%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"        AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AppTest.aspx.cs"      Inherits="AppTest.Screens.UploadFile" %>




<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"    runat="server">
<style>

    .hidden{
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<div class="row">
     <h2>File Upload</h2>
        <br />

        <asp:Panel ID="panelUpload" runat="server">
           <p> <asp:Label ID="lblFileUpload" Width="300px"  runat="server">Select the file:</asp:Label>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUP" runat="server" /></p>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDdl" runat="server">Paciente</asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">


                </asp:DropDownList>

            </p>
            <br />


            </asp:Panel>



    <div id="divId" class="hidden">
        </br>
<h2>Cadastro de paciente</h2>
        <br />
<p>
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server">Name:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>

</p>


        <p>
<asp:Label ID="lblLast" runat="server">Last Name:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>

</p>

        <p>
<asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server">Age:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>

</p>

<br />


</div>
  <p>
       <div class="col-md-6">
   <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Inserir"/>
           </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
<button>New</button>
           </div>
</p>
    </div>


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptPlaceHolder1" ID="scripts"     runat="server">

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('button').on('click', function () {
            $('#divId').show(); // aparece o div

        });
});




</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Use firebug if you are using Firefox, you will get the error in cosole

Comment: You can use show on class also

Comment: You could start by adding a type attribute to your script tag "text/javascript"

Comment: Thanks! the type attribute was one of the problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So When you do Button click your page is loaded again because postback occurs. in your aspx page you have defined your class as hidden in aspx page. So you can prevent this by this way.

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
            $('#divId').show(); // aparece o div
            return false;

        });
```

There are multiple way of doing this, I have shown you one way.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me, the missing return false was another problem!

Comment: Thanks, what was other issue ?

Comment: The other problem was the missing type attribute.